# How to create a script in Linux that makes a pyramid of asterisks with the pattern 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17 centered

Tags: linux

I'm trying to write a shell script to print a pyramid of asterisks like this:

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
```

Below is my attempt so far. When I run it, I get some errors that say arithmetic expression required. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (( i = 1; i <= n, i++ )); do
    for (( k = i; k <= n, k++ )); do
        echo -ne " "
    done

    for (( j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1, j++ )); do
        echo -ne "*"
    done

    echo
done
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong, RTFM ;-) Hint: commas.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of an arithmetic for-loop uses two semicolons, *not* a semicolon and a comma:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )); do
```

(The individual components may contain commas — for example, `i++, j++` is an expression that increments both `i` and `j` — but that has no specific relevance to the `for`.)

Comment: I fixed it. Now it doesn't show up errors but when I run the script nothing happens. It just goes to a new command line.

Comment: @arry617: Did you remember to initialize `n` to the desired value?

Comment: Newbie mistake. Thanks so much for the help. I got it working now.

Answer (score -2):

echo "enter value for n"

read n

for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ))

```
do

for (( k = i; k <= n; k++ ))

do

    echo -ne " "

done


for (( j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++ ))

do

    echo -ne "*"

done
```

echo " "

done

this one is right program with corrected syntax

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. Also please fix the formatting of your answer.